# Change from dependent visa to work permit

Tags: working-visas, germany

I am looking for some information. In my case my husband is onsite in Germany from   his Indian company and I am on dependent visa. recently I got a job with unlimited work contract but my husband's visa expires next year. and I am not eligible for blue card as my salary criteria does not matched.  Is there the possibility of us changing the residence types while within Germany, I from dependent to my own work permit visa, and my husband from work visa to spouse dependent visa?